# TypeScript: Derive interface from other interface by re-using the keys but not the values

Tags: typescript

Given an interface A

```
interface A {
  foo: string;
  bar: boolean;
}
```

I want to derive another interface B with the following properties

```
interface B {
  foo: SomeOtherInterface;
  bar: SomeOtherInterface;
}
```

Is it possible to do so?

So far I'm able to extract the keys via `type X = keyof A`, but I'm not able to derive the interface B with those keys.

Unfortunately the following **does NOT work**:

```
interface B {
  [K keyof A]: SomeOtherInterface
}
```

Bonus question:
What about interface C?

```
interface C {
  foo: SomeOtherGenericInterface<string>;
  bar: SomeOtherGenericInterface<boolean>;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Given an interface A
>
> ```
> interface A {
>   foo: string;
>   bar: boolean;
> }
> ```
>
> I want to derive another interface B with the following properties
>
> ```
> interface B {
>   foo: SomeOtherInterface;
>   bar: SomeOtherInterface;
> }
> ```

You can do it like this:

```
interface A {
  foo: string;
  bar: boolean;
}

interface SomeOtherInterface {
    other: string;
}

type B = {
  [K in keyof A]: SomeOtherInterface
}

// Example
const b: B = {
    foo: { other: "foo" },
    bar: { other: "bar" }
}
```

> Bonus question: What about interface C?
>
> ```
> interface C {
>   foo: SomeOtherGenericInterface<string>;
>   bar: SomeOtherGenericInterface<boolean>;
> }
> ```

I *think* this is doing what you want:

```
interface SomeOtherGenericInterface<T> {
    value: T;
}

type DerivedTypeWithSomeOtherGenericValues<T, V extends { [K in keyof T]: any }> = {
    [K in keyof T]: SomeOtherGenericInterface<V[K]>
}

type C = DerivedTypeWithSomeOtherGenericValues<A, { foo: string, bar: number }>;

// Example
const c: C = {
    foo: { value: "foo" },
    bar: { value: 123 }
}
```

[Example in the Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%2F%2F%20B%20derives%20keys%20from%20A%20but%20uses%20SomeOtherInterface%20type%0Ainterface%20A%20%7B%0A%09foo%3A%20string%3B%0A%09bar%3A%20boolean%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20SomeOtherInterface%20%7B%0A%09other%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Atype%20B%20%3D%20%7B%0A%09%5BK%20in%20keyof%20A%5D%3A%20SomeOtherInterface%0A%7D%0A%0A%2F%2F%20Example%0Aconst%20b%3A%20B%20%3D%20%7B%0A%09foo%3A%20%7B%20other%3A%20%22foo%22%20%7D%2C%0A%09bar%3A%20%7B%20other%3A%20%22bar%22%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%2F%2F%20C%20derives%20keys%20from%20A%20but%20uses%20SomeOtherGenericInterface%3CT%3E%20with%20type%20lookups%0Ainterface%20SomeOtherGenericInterface%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%09value%3A%20T%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Atype%20DerivedTypeWithSomeOtherGenericValues%3CT%2C%20V%20extends%20%7B%20%5BK%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20any%20%7D%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0A%09%5BK%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20SomeOtherGenericInterface%3CV%5BK%5D%3E%0A%7D%0A%0Atype%20C%20%3D%20DerivedTypeWithSomeOtherGenericValues%3CA%2C%20%7B%20foo%3A%20string%2C%20bar%3A%20number%20%7D%3E%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20Example%0Aconst%20c%3A%20C%20%3D%20%7B%0A%09foo%3A%20%7B%20value%3A%20%22foo%22%20%7D%2C%0A%09bar%3A%20%7B%20value%3A%20123%20%7D%0A%7D)

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for your answer! It's `[K in keyof T]` that does the magic. Is it also possible to invert the optional and required properties in the derived interface B? So if in A `foo` is required and `bar` is not, is it possible to have `foo` optional and `bar` required in interface B?

Comment: I don't think its possible to literally invert them as you describe, but you can controll whether the derived type has optional or not by using `?`.

Comment: Yeah I know of making them all optional. Unfortunately in my case I need the exact inverted values. Thanks for your time answering the question! :)

Answer (score 0):

What exactly does not work with the below? Do you get a compile error or does it not work conceptually?

```
interface B {
    [K keyof A]: SomeOtherInterface
}
```

could it be that you have to do

```
interface B<A> {
    [K keyof A]: SomeOtherInterface
}
```

Also I am wondering what is the aim of having a type like `B` where all properties are of the exact same type?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it does not work as you have proposed because interfaces cannot be created this way. It's only working with types and with `[K in typeof A]`. Aaron did the correct thing there.