# Typescript create interface having keys of another interface

Tags: typescript

```
interface A{
    x: string;
    y: string;
    z: string;
    // maybe later something more
}
interface B{
    [K in keyof A]: Boolean;
}
```

Why isn't it working? I want to create something like that, but dynamically:

```
interface B{
    x: Boolean;
    y: Boolean;
    z: Boolean;
    // maybe later something more
}
```

Comment: change `interface B{` to `type B = {`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript: Derive interface from other interface by re-using the keys but not the values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42560746/typescript-derive-interface-from-other-interface-by-re-using-the-keys-but-not-t)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't use `Boolean` use `boolean`.

Also mapped types only work with `type` not `interface`, there is little difference between the two, so this should work

```
type Bar = {
  [key in keyof A]: boolean
}
```

Also, this mapped type could be written using the redefined mapped type `Record`:

```
type Bar = Record<keyof A, boolean>
```

Comment: Why boolean is better? Could you give an example when it makes difference?

Comment: @MateuszKisielMateuszKisiel in short, referring to book "Effective TypeScript" by O'Reilly, Item 10: Avoid Object Wrapper Types (String, Number, Boolean, Symbol, BigInt), — otherwise mixup will happen — for example, `string` is assignable to `String`, but `String` is not assignable to `string`

Answer (score 3):

Try following:

```
interface A{
    x: string;
    y: string;
    z: string;
    // maybe later something more
}


type Bar = {
  [key in keyof A]: boolean
}

interface B extends Bar { }
```